# what kind of encoding is this?

Tags: javascript, xml, jena, dbpedia

I've got some data from dbpedia using jena and since jena's output is based on xml so there are some circumstances that xml characters need to be treated differently like following :

```
Guns n &amp;#039; Roses
```

I just want to know what kind of econding is this?
I want decode/encode my input based on above encode(r) with the help of javascript and send it back to a servlet.

(edited post if you remove the space between & and amp you will get the correct character since in stackoverflow I couldn't find a way to do that I decided to put like that!)

Comment: That's encoded twice, and that's (most likely) a bug. Where does this occur?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be XML entity encoding, and a *numeric character reference* (decimal).

> A numeric character reference refers to a character by its [Universal
>   Character Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set)/[Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) code point, and uses the format

You can get some info here: [List of XML and HTML character entity references on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Your character is number 39, being the apostrophe: `'`, which can also be referenced with a *character entity reference*: `&apos;`.

To decode this using Javascript, you could use for example [`php.js`](http://phpjs.org/), which has an [`html_entity_decode()`](http://phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode:424) function (note that it depends on [get_html_translation_table()](http://phpjs.org/functions/get_html_translation_table:416)).

---

**UPDATE**: in reply to your edit: Basically that is the same, the only difference is that it was *encoded twice* (possibly by mistake). `&amp;` is the ampersand: `&`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an SGML/HTML/XML numeric [character entity reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference).

In this case for an apostrophe `'`.